# MongoDB:The cursor was closed before next() completed

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I was using Mongodb driver(Java) to find documents by `batchCursor()` method.
But sometime, I received error:

> com.mongodb.MongoException: The cursor was closed before next()
>   completed.

I retried but always receive that error.

My configuration:

```
collection.find(filter)
.cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait)
.oplogReplay(oplogTimestamp != null)
.noCursorTimeout(true)
.batchSize(this.batchSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like I used `CursorType.TailableAwait` config by mistake. I changed to `CursorType.NonTailable` and it have worked well.

`CursorType.TailableAwait` has an other function: (It's similar with how we use tail -f in linux)

Mongo Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/